# Cannot hit break point in java app when running the whole junit integration test class

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, junit

Newbie question:
java 8 app, using JUnit to test. Using maven, IntelliJ.

Say this integration test is `tests.api.users.TestCreateUser`, inside it has some test cases say `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, ...
I set a break point in the java app itself for debugging.

integration tests → java app (running in debug mode, with breakpoint)

If I run the `tests.api.users.TestCreateUser.t1` only (from IntelliJ you can choose to run or debug this test only), it'll hit my breakpoint.

Then I try to run this complete test class `tests.api.users.TestCreateUser`, it did run all tests in this class, but won't hit my break point.

How to fix this please?

Comment: Did you run the whole suite of tests using run or debug?  You can use debug to run the whole test classes.  I dont recall having issues with this in IntelliJ

Comment: i didn't run the whole complete 50+ test classed, was only focusing on this test class only. Will give it a try, thx !

Comment: Yes, from the description it looks like you're executing it via "Run" not via "Debug". 
You can determine what is running by the active bottom tool window. It can be "Run" (Alt + 4) or "Debug" (Alt + 5).

Answer (score 0):

OK, for each integration test (or test class or ...), there's a JUnit run/debug configuration in IntelliJ.  In my case, I needed to set "VM options" properly so it's pointing to the server under test.
For the above none working case, it was not pointing to my local server under debugging.
Your case might be different, but I'm contributing as a newbie.